# Google calendar API give access to gservice account programmatically

Tags: spring, calendar, google-calendar-api

My application is accessing registered google calendars (shared) and adding/syncing calendar events to these calendars.

But before my application can access these calendars, I need to share the calendar to `sapmle-application@my-api-project-ato-ni-bai.iam.gserviceaccount.com` via `Settings > Share with specific people`

After, my application can add calendar events programmatically.

What I want to do now is... In my application.. I want to register a google calendar .. and the `Share with specific people` part will be done programmatically.. so I do not need to go to all calendar settings and share it with my application's gservice account.

I just enter/add/register a google calendar id, and my application will run some codes that will share the calendar to my gservice.

I am not sure if this is possible and how to do this... for now, I want everything done on my application without opening the calendar's settings (assumming I already have the list of google calendar ids I need to add/register to my application).

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You could create an application that logs in a user using Oauth2 requesting access to their calendar account.  You will need the following scope.

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar

Once you have access to their Google calendar account you can simply add a acl record for the service account [acl.insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/acl/insert) to which ever calendar you like.

But you still have to have the users permission to do this.

## note

You should really only be using a service account for calendars that you (the developer) control. You should be logging normal users in using Oauth2 not requiring that they share their calendars with your service account.  This not what service accounts are intended for.